# next() function in jQuery is not showing the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and in a project I fell into a problem. What I want is, there is a `select` box, which have some values. When my page loads, I want that if this `select` box has a certain value selected, its immediate `div` will appear automatically, otherwise, that `div` will be hidden.

My problem, here no event is occurring, it all will happen right after the page loads.

I did the same kind of work in another page, but there the `div` appears when I "select" a certain value. But, here I want this to happen when the page loads.

So what I tried :

html code :

```
<select class="selector">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="selector">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="show" style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="text">Sample Text</textarea>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")
     $(this).next('.show').show();
});
</script>
```

So, what I want is, if the `.selector` has the value "volvo", its next div(which has the class "show") will show up, otherwise not. Here, I am not using any change event. I want this happen after the page has been loaded.

I tried this too :

```
if($('.selector').val()=="volvo")
   $(this).next().show();
```

But same result, nothing happens, the  doesn't show up.

What should I do now ?

N.B.: Please notice that there are multiple `<select>` elements.

Comment: `$('.selector').next()` should work.

Comment: So you want that when page loads the value of select option to be checked and then hide/show div?

Comment: Yes, I exactly want that to happen @user3260861

Answer (score 5):

You are using `this` in document-ready handler, where it referees to document. You should bind *change* event with *select* and trigger it on page load.

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Bind change event
    $('.selector').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
            $(this).next('.show').show();
        }
    }).change(); //Trigger on page load
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using that in `document.ready` `this` doesn't refer to select.

You should say

```
 $('.selector').next('.show').show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/68/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution. Hope its work for you :-

```
<select class="selector">
<option value="select">select</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div class="show" style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="text">Sample Text</textarea>
</div>
```

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".selector").on("change", function(){
    $val = $(this).val()
   // alert($val);

    if($val == "volvo"){
        $(".show").show();
    }else{
     $(".show").hide();
    }
})

});
```

Checkout below link

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ananddeepsingh/kzk9re0k/)